# fire event from bool setter

Tags: c#, events

I'm trying to fire an event when a bool has actually changed value. I read that using a custom set and get method is one of the ways to do this. But I keep getting `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

```
Public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
public delegate void ballEvents();
public static event ballEvents OnBallStop;

private bool _previousValue = true;
private bool _ballStopped = true;
public bool BallHasStopped {
    get {return _ballStopped;}
    set {
        _ballStopped = value;
        if (_ballStopped != _previousValue){
            _previousValue = _ballStopped;
            if(value == true) {
                print("stop");
                OnBallStop(); // this causes the error
            } else {
                print("moving");
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you do not need to keep `_previousValue` - before you do the assignment to `_ballStopped`, you've got the previous value in `_ballStopped`, and new value in `value` - so you can just have `if (_ballStopped != value) { _ballStopped = value; doWhatever(); }` in the setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an event has no handlers it is `null`, and so cannot be invoked.  You can check for `null` and not invoke it unless there are handlers.

Comment: Or he can have `Events` and Raise them. Checking is not required in events.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Yes, there are technically a ton of alternatives; this is just one.